# Can you recover from a ChatConnector Bad Request error?

Tags: node.js, botframework

Sometimes the `ChatConnector` will fail to send a message to a backend. It happens for instance when the message is too big:

`Request to 'https://slack.botframework.com/v3/conversations/xyz/activities/...’ failed: [400] Bad Request 
at Request._callback (/app/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js:514:46)`

**Can you "recover" from this when the message was sent with `session.send(msg)`?**

I understand it is async so we can only find out "later" whether it worked or not, but I was hoping there might be a mechanism to capture the error, check which message failed and (maybe) tweak it and retry?

The only way I have found so far is to add a listener to the bot itself:

`bot.on('error', function (e) {
  ...
});`

but it seems to me it does not tell you which message failed.

Comment: How big is this message exactly? [400 Bad Request](https://httpstatuses.com/400) error is exactly what it sounds like - "The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)." - Since your message does not match the API input requirements, there is nothing to "recover" from.

Comment: Thanks @NilsW. It is a size issue - we have tested this extensively. It's one of the challenges with the ChatConnector: sometimes it will return a 400 when

Comment: Sorry pressed enter too fast, could not edit. It is a size issue - we have tested this extensively. Each backend (Slack, Skype...) apply their own size limit to the messages you can send to them, and I don't believe it's documented. The 400 error returned by/to the ChatConnector is (I think) just an indication that something went wrong - not an API mismatch. When I say "recover", I mean we have a mechanism to check whether the problem is "likely" a size issue and we can rebuild/resend the message. And alternatively, we can at least send a message to the user saying something failed.

Comment: And to keep things generic: my question was, how do you find out, using the bot framework, that a backend messaging system (Slack, Skype...) failed to accept a message?

Comment: @NilsW Here is the size limit issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/985

Comment: @NilsW Just wondering whether you had additional thoughts on this? It's a difficult one to handle for us since it does not seem like the framework is providing hooks.